# Mac OS X Mavericks CMake + Xcode 5.1 Makefiles won't compile because of argument "-mlong-branch"

Tags: xcode, cmake

I use CMake 2.8.12.2 to generate Makefiles on Mac OS X Maveericks to compile my projects in command line.

Recently my Xcode has updated itself to version 5.1 and thus has changed the clang version (which is now: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)).

Now I compile projects based on automatically generated Makefiles (by CMake) I get the following error :

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mlong-branch' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
```

I can solve it by manually removing from the link.txt and flags.make generated files the `-m-long-branch` option but each time I call `ccmake`, I have to do it again.

Does anyone has an idea how I can configurate CMake in order not to add this -mlong-branch option in the makefiles please?

Thanks in advance for your help.
JimN